# Using a lookup field to filter a report or query in Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I've been looking for a while to see whether it is possible to limit the results in a report by using a lookup field in a form. First, a little context. I'm making a database to store accessibility information for buildings at a University for the Union. I need to be able to produce a report showing what user-selected qualities a building has, like ramp access or a staffed reception.

I've stored all these features in a table of their own so users can edit them, and then used lookup fields to select these features for buildings. The issue now is running the query to produce the report.
If I hard code in values to the query like `...WHERE [Buildings].[Accessibility Features].Value = 2 AND [Buildings].[Accessibility Features].Value = 8;` I get sensible results. If I use the `IN()` function (which I have got to work with the field using the `DoCmd.OpenReport()` function) I get returned all buildings that have *either* feature 2 **or** feature 8 which isn't that handy. The aforementioned `DoCmd.OpenReport()` function doesn't appear to work when stringing together AND statements.

I've tried using VBA to assemble the SQL code as follows (feeding a parameter into the Criteria box preceded by the appropriate statement):

```
If Me.BuildingFeatSelect.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Must select at least one feature"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set ctl = Me.BuildingFeatSelect
For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
    strWhere = strWhere & ctl.ItemData(varItem) & " AND Buildings.[Accessibility Features].Value = "
Next varItem

strWhere = Left(strWhere, Len(strWhere) - 48)
MsgBox strWhere, , Output

Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim rst As Recordset
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Copy of Building Features 2")
qdf.Parameters(0) = strWhere
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset

rst.Close
qdf.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
```

This gets me nowhere quickly. It just throws an error about parameter types. I've tried setting the type using the Parameter window but this doesn't work.

Is there an efficient way to generate a report based on multiple entries in a lookup box?

Thanks for your help, and sorry for the long question.

Comment: Hi, instead of left use trim function. Also, are your [Accessibility feature] numeric or strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you got it halfway right. You can feed parameters to a query, one value for each parameter that the query uses.
In your query, you are using just one parameter, and you are assigning it a string. This is not the proper way to use parameters. You would better build an SQL select and filter it based on the string you created.

```
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim rst As Recordset
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", "SELECT * from tblBuildingFeatures WHERE [Accessibility Features]=" & strWhere & ";")
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
```

That will filter the query.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! Thanks. To get it to work the way I wanted, I also added a Name for the query, ran the script and then created a Report for the new query before deleting the new query and adding the lines `DoCmd.OpenReport "...", acViewPreview` and `DoCmd.DeletObject acQuery"..."` Again, very grateful for the help!!!